# What's C/C++ equivalent of Java's Async Task

Tags: java, c++, c

In Java there's Async task

```
private class AddTaskFeature extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    AddTaskFeature(String _process){
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... unused) {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
    }
}
```

What's C/C++ equivalent of that code?

Answer (score 3):

Up until C++11 there was no unified threading support for C++, not to mention more advanced `Future`-based classes. In C++11 take a look at [std::future](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future).

I think you can find what you need in boost, however. boost::thread has classes which should allow you to do what you need.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/thread.html

Answer (score 1):

AsyncTask is provided by Android not Java. On many platforms you can use pthreads to do multithreading. On iOS you can use dispatch queues. You should look up your platform's programming manual.

Answer (score 0):

You would use a lambda or a class that overrides operator( ).

```
struct MyTask {
  Result operator()() { 
    // do work here
    return Result{};
  }
};
auto fut = std::async( MyTask{} );
fut.wait( );
auto result = fut.get( );
```

Or

```
auto fut = std::async( []() { 
  // do work
  return Result{};
} );
fut.wait( );
auto result = fut.get( );
```

There is no progress, but one can supply args and the result of the work is the result of the future.

```
auto fut = std::async( []( int a, int b ) { return a + b; }, 5, 4  );
assert( fut.get( ) == 9 );
```